# Money problem...probability spend in particular time

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, exponential-function, central-limit-theorem

A child puts money in piggy bank every day ,
in particular 10 , 20 , 30 , 40 , 50 , or 60 cents with the same probability . Find the
probability of spending at least 80 days before having collected 30 euros. Suggestion:
use the central limit theorem

Comment: What do you mean by "timek" besides demonstrating the small amount of effort spent to even write down the question properly??? And more importantly, what have you tried?

Comment: i think...
lets say S the sum of the money in 80 days.....
we want P(S<30) .....
Sn=x1+x2...xn.....

μ=1/6(0,1+0,2+0.3+0.4+0.6)=2,1/6.....
days=80*,1/6......
      ,,,,, E(x^2)=1/6(0,1^2 etc...(0,6)^2) ,,,,,but the number gets too weird

Comment: sorry but my english are not that good

Comment: Do you know how to solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

Let's choose our unit of money to be euro. Define $X_j=$money deposited on $j$-th day. $\{X_n\}$ are independent and identically distributed. 
$$\mu=E(X_j)=\sum_{k=1}^6{k\over10}\times{1\over6}={7\over20}\\
\sigma^2=\text{var}(X_j)=\sum_{k=1}^6\left({k\over10}\right)^2\times{1\over6}-\mu^2={7\over240}$$
We'll use Central Limit Theorem to approximate $S=\sqrt{80}({1\over80}\sum_{j=1}^{80}X_j-\mu)$ with $N(0,\sigma^2)$. Required probability
$$
P\left({\sqrt{80}}(S+\sqrt{80}\mu)\le30\right)=P\left(S\le{\sqrt5\over10}\right)\approx{1\over\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt5\over10}e^{-{x^2\over2\sigma^2}}dx\approx0.9
$$